# Spring Webflux 2.5.x + Spring Cloud + Zipkin: Not able to get Zipkin metrics

Tags: java, spring-cloud, grafana, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

Small question regarding Spring Webflux project, with Spring Cloud please.

In my small Spring Webflux app, I am currently using

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I see the traces fine in m Zipkin server, very happy.

But I was also expecting to be able to get some metrics, such as

```
zipkin_collector_messages_total
zipkin_collector_bytes_total
zipkin_collector_spans_total
zipkin_collector_spans_dropped_total
zipkin_collector_messages_dropped_total

histogram_quantile(0.9, http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{method="POST",uri="/api/v2/spans"})
```

However, while I am seeing the traces in Zipkin server, and "some" zipkin metrics, such as `zipkin_reporter_spans_total` I am not getting Zipkin related metrics at all.

May I ask how to get above mentioned metrics please?

Thank you

Comment: have you figured this out? I am confused as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, still hoping for someone to enlighten on this :)

Comment: try skywalking as tracing receiver, it has some out-of-the-box metrics such as p99, average resp time etc.

Comment: Thanks! I agree there might be over better solutions out there, but I just want to figure out how to get those Zipkin metrics!